# I don't get response from DatagramPacket with Java

Tags: java, sockets, packet, datagram

I want to check if one of a remote host server accepts UDP Packets on a specific port. With SocketServer I can set up a TCP/IP connection and it worked, but I must use UDP.

```
DatagramSocket ds;
DatagramPacket dp;
byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
InetAddress IAddress = new InetAddress.getByName("86.55.X.X");    

ds = new DatagramSocket();
ds.setSoTimeout(100);
ds.connect(IAddress, 1122);
ds.send(dp);
ds.isConnected();
dp = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);
ds.receive(dp);
ds.close();
```

The code above it should work, I don't know how to test it because I don't find any host/soft which/where I could run/test the code above. I'm trying to test it on a remote host. The remote host has Windows OS and Firewall disabled. It has a router and the firewall is also disabled. I can access the remote server and make changes in the router. My question is: can a remote host accept UDP packets if the only opened ports are for TCP/IP? (Port forward).
In the router control panel I can make port forward for only TCP/IP.

Comment: Test it using `localhost` (127.0.0.1), which is your own computer. You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check network activity. UDP is part of TCP/IP protocol stack.

Comment: What error you are getting on server. I don't think you need to use connect() for UDP sockets.. why can't you use just send(packet)..

Comment: if your scene is with NAT, the remote server is behind router/nat (with private IP -10.*/172.xx.*/192.168.*) and you don't have port-forwarded the UDP-port.... can't work.

Comment: Calling isConnected() and ignoring the result is pointless. It's pointless anyway. If you weren't connected, connect() would have thrown an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try on `localhost` (on `localhost` you can easily debug your software on what is going on when something is received).

Moreover you should want to bind your `DatagramSocket` on a port in order to receive a packet. And you do not need a `DatagramSocket` to be connected when sending.

Comment: +1 And the router has to be configured to allow UDP packets. TCP alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the following variable to your JRE

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  ...
```

Comment: Why? I don't see any evidence that this is the problem.